# Display brightness problem on ThinkPad X1 Carbon 2015 (3rd Gen)

Tags: display, brightness, thinkpad

I am using ThinkPad X1 Carbon 2015 (3rd Gen) with 1920x1080 display (no touchscreen), running Ubuntu 14.04 with all patches applied (14.04.2 equivalent, I think).

I used this post: [Lenovo X1 Carbon 2015 3rd gen 20 BS - trackpoint, clickpad and wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599477/lenovo-x1-carbon-2015-3rd-gen-20-bs-trackpoint-clickpad-and-wifi)

> 1. Create `/etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf` containing only one line 
>          options thinkpad_acpi force_load=1
> 2. Change `/etc/default/grub` as follows:
>
>    ```
>    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
>    ```
> 3. `sudo update-grub`
> 4. Add `echo 167 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to `/etc/rc.local`
> 5. reboot

This procedure produced the following result:

- Display brightness remains the minimum level (0). I installed indicator-brightness and set to maximum (15) but it doesn't help.
- I changed brightness from display settings and no changes are happening.
- Fn+F5/F6 combinations do not work. On-screen display can be seen, but brightness cannot be changed by these key compbinations (actually, this is a small problem. I could change manually display brightness if everything was working fine).
- In `/var/log/dmesg`, there is one entry

  ```
  [    1.549321] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface not available, thinkpad_acpi native brightness control enabled
  ```

The worst difficulty I am facing is the minimum brightness of display.

Comment: please see my answer -

http://askubuntu.com/questions/599477/lenovo-x1-carbon-2015-3rd-gen-20-bs-trackpoint-clickpad-and-wifi/599831#599831

Comment: having the same problem now. @brett that solution worked for me for a little while, giving control via the indicator brightness widget, but after a recent update (or some other change I was not aware of) this no longer works.

Comment: @philchalmers - I had the same experience too with Linux Kernel 3.13.0-47-generic.  I removed the brightness widget and re-installed after auto upgrade to 3.13.0-48-generic.  If you are there and brightness widgert is not working, remove and re-install.

Comment: @brett on Kernel 3.13.0-49-generic, but removing and reinstalling didn't fix the issue. I don't think it's the widget that's the issue though. The display brightness adjustment in the Ubuntu settings GUI doesn't work either (it previously worked without having to install the widget, which I assume is just a convenient front end to this anyway). So it's something else that has broken the patch.

Answer (score 1):

Intermediate self-resolution. My ThinkPad X1 Carbon (3rd Gen) now displays maximum (not minimum) brightness.

From the previous procedure, I deleted the entry in `/etc/rc.local` beginning with `echo 167 > ...`. This made sense.

No other settings were changed.

Brightness control still does not work, but the current situation is far better than being permanently stuck on minimum brightness.

Still, is there any solution to make brightness control in ThinkPad X1 Carbon 2015 (3rd Gen)?

Comment: FYI @terakinizers upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10 seems to do the trick. It even fixed the aux mouse buttons for me, so now everything appears to be working fine.