# How to make ClickButtons work without affecting the Touchpad (X1C)

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad, trackpoint

There's a simple way to enable the ClickButtons on a Lenovo X1 Carbon that I already found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/599831/167365

```
echo "options psmouse proto=imps" > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
```

However, if they're enabled using this way, I can't use two finger scrolling on the touchpad anymore. Is there any way to make both working simultaniously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Ubuntu 15.04, ClickButtons seem to work automatically, so there's no longer any action needed to make them work.