# TrackPoint on Lenovo X1 Carbon 3rd gen. not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, trackpoint

I'm trying to get the TrackPoint to work in Ubuntu on my Lenovo X1 Carbon 3rd gen. laptop.

I just did a fresh install of 16.04 LTS (along with `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` after installation), and as before, the TrackPoint (the red "dot" in the middle of the keyboard) is not responsive at all.

Some output that might help someone solve the problem:

```
user@host:~$ sudo evtest
No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
Available devices:
/dev/input/event0:  Lid Switch
/dev/input/event1:  Sleep Button
/dev/input/event2:  Power Button
/dev/input/event3:  AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
/dev/input/event4:  Video Bus
/dev/input/event5:  PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
/dev/input/event6:  ThinkPad Extra Buttons
/dev/input/event7:  HDA Intel PCH Mic
/dev/input/event8:  HDA Intel PCH Headphone
/dev/input/event9:  Integrated Camera
/dev/input/event10: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3
/dev/input/event11: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7
/dev/input/event12: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8
```

The TrackPoint is not listed at all. On my 1st gen. Lenovo X1 Carbon the TrackPoint is listed as:

```
/dev/input/event5:  TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint
```

I have made sure that the TrackPoint is enabled in BIOS. I have also tried to listen on all the devices listed above, and none of them registers any movement at all for the TrackPoint.

Initially the physical buttons above the TouchPad didn't work either, but I fixed that by adding the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/touchpad.conf`:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

but this did not change anything related to the TrackPoint it seems.

I have read a bunch of other articles regarding the Lenovo X1 Carbon 3rd gen. and Ubuntu on this site, but I can't find any solutions...

**Update 2016-08-31: Turns out there is a hardware issue with the TrackPoint on my laptop.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out there was a hardware issue with the TrackPoint on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use instrucion from 1st post

[Lenovo X1 Carbon 2015 3rd gen 20 BS - trackpoint, clickpad and wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599477/lenovo-x1-carbon-2015-3rd-gen-20-bs-trackpoint-clickpad-and-wifi)

> TrackPad Buttons:
>
> /etc/modprobe.d/touchpad.conf:
>
> options psmouse proto=imps
>
> update-initramfs -u

Comment: As I wrote in the question above, I have already tried that.